# How to write a code in Haskell to filter out Nothing values from a list

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I wish to "map a list and drop it if the map function returns Nothing". I am doing as follows:-

```
    filteredList f l = map to_int (mapMaybe f l)
```

The `to_int` function here is as follows

```
    to_int some_value = case some_value of
      Just a -> a
      Nothing -> 0
```

This although logically correct to me, is not working as it should. Can someone please explain where I am wrong here?

Comment: do you want to map Nothing to zero or do you want to remove values from the list? in one case you are doing a mapping, in the other a fold

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to implement already exists. Indeed, [**`mapMaybe :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:mapMaybe) will take function and a list, call the function on the elements of the list, and retrieve the items that returned a `Just …` object. The items are unwrapped from the `Just` data constructor.

This function is defined in the [**`base`** package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base), but not in the `Prelude`. This means that you should import this from the `Data.Maybe` module:

```
import Data.Maybe(mapMaybe)

filteredList :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> [b]
filteredList = mapMaybe
```

You can specialize this for example with `a ~ b ~ Integer` and thus use this as `(Integer -> Maybe Integer) -> [Integer] -> [Integer]`.

You can also implement this function yourself, for example with list comprehension:

```
filteredList :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> [b]
filteredList f l = [ y | Just y <- map f l ]
```

Here we thus use pattern matching to ensure that we receive an `Just x` pattern. If the pattern does not match, then this item is skipped. We also unwrap the `y` from the `Just y` pattern, and use this as item to put in the list.

Comment: The type signature for the function should be (Integer -> Maybe Integer) -> [Integer] -> [Integer] however, and upon trying this I am getting the errors "Variable not in scope: catMaybes :: t0 -> t2" and "Variable not in scope: mapMaybe :: t -> t1 -> t0". I faced this error previously too. Why am I encountering it?

Comment: @Obsidian_42: what exactly is the `mapMaybe`? I had the idea that `mapMaybe f l` should return a list of `Maybe Integer`s, but the error says you never implemented a `mapMaybe` function to produce a list of `Maybe Integer`s.

Comment: The mapMaybe function is a Haskell built-in function actually, which is why I am quite surprised as well. It is supposedly in Data.Maybe module and my code doesn't work despite importing that module and then using this. In any case, it isn't a function I am defining so the error is definitely surprising.

Comment: @Obsidian_42: The error is not suprising: it is in the `base` package, but not in the `Prelude`. You need to import it with `import Data.Maybe(mapMaybe)` but if you use `mapMaybe` (as defined there), than that is sufficient, then `filteredList` is simply `filteredList = mapMaybe`.